# Where to put my dll files using F#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, f#

I have a library with both managed and unmanaged C#, C++ dll files. I want to reference it from F#. Where can I place the C#, C++ dll files? I can not place them in the application folder (I must have `copy local = false`) and it will be only me who will use the program. I have tried windows/system32, GAC using setup and adding PATH variable pointing to a folder with all the dll files but none of it seems to work.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Honestly, why can't you have them where it makes the most sense (the application folder)? Is this a real constraint?

Comment: I will copy the one application into 60 places and run it -> for parametric studies and as a backup of the applications for the future. The dll I am talking about is 50 MB (VTK) and it is thus waste of space as I will run more and more parametric studies

Comment: If you add a search path to your system where the dlls can be found, it should be loaded without a problem. If that doesn't happen you can try to use the free, excellent Process Monitor to see where the system tries to load your dlls from and then just put them there.

Answer (score 0):

When building your application in Visual Studio, it looks for the references in all the default folders (depending on your OS, .NET Framework version and other things) but also in locations you specified in the project configuration. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer, click Properties and go to the Reference Paths tab. Add C:\MyDllFolder or anything.

If you do this in all your applications which are using that dll, you could just have it sitting there once.

Comment: I have tried that but even when I set up `copy local = false` to all the dlls they are copied to bin/release folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify dll locations [MSDN : Specifying an Assembly's Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx) or maybe use something like

```
Assembly.LoadFrom
```

if you want dynamics.